# Solving recurrence T(n) = T(n/5) + T(7n/10) + Θ(n)

Tags: math, recurrence, big-o

I want to solve this recurrence with an accuracy of Θ:
T(n) = T(n/5) + T(7n/10) + Θ(n)

I can solving typical recurrence but I don't know what to do with this one as it doesn't match to any case of master theorem.

Any help or hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Akra-Bazzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) generalization of the master theorem.

If the Theta(n) term were replaced by something smaller, like Theta(1) or Theta(sqrt(n)) in this case, you could simply find the value of alpha so that n^alpha = (n/5)^alpha + (7n/10)^alpha by factoring out n^alpha. However, if you do that, you get alpha = 0.84, and n^0.84 is asymptotically smaller than Theta(n), so the contribution from the Theta(n) terms dominate if you iterate the recursion until the arguments are small. The result is that T(n) is Theta(n), though with different constants than the Theta(n) in the  recursion.